# Crear una Matriz de Objetos Dinámica en C++

Tags: c++, poo, punteros

Cada elemento de la matriz, es un objeto Numero. ¿es con triple puntero? (***)

Comment: **No**. Si el arreglo es estático, cada elemento es un puntero *simple*: `Numero *matriz[x]`. Si el propio arreglo es dinámico, cada elementos sigue siendo *simple*, pero hay que añadir un nivel de indirección para el propio arreglo: `Numero **matriz`. Accedes igual en ambos casos: `*matrix[x]`, mejor aún (que lo tenemos), usando el operador `->`: `matriz[x]->...`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si, lo tengo creado como **matriz pero al intentar usar metodos set y get del objeto no me reconoce el -> como un puntero valido. solo el '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Crear una Matriz de Objetos Dinámica en C++

Tienes básicamente dos opciones

1. Gestionar múltiples vectores

   - Gestión de la memoria más complicada
   - Múltiples reservas de memoria
   - Operaciones más lentas ya que los datos no estarán adyacentes
   - Necesitas un puntero doble
   - El acceso a las posiciones es más natural

     ```
     const int filas = 10;
     const int columnas = 5;

     // Reserva de memoria
     int ** matriz = new int*[filas];
     for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
       matriz[i] = new int[columnas];

     // ejemplo de acceso a datos
     matriz[2][3] = 5; 

     // Liberación de la memoria
     for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
       delete[] matriz[i];

     delete[] matriz;
     ```
2. Gestionar un único vector

   - Una única reserva de memoria
   - Todas las posiciones son adyacentes
   - Acceso a las posiciones un poco más complejo (es preferible encapsularlo en una función)
   - Necesitas un puntero simple

     ```
     const int filas = 10;
     const int columnas = 5;

     // Reserva de memoria
     int * matriz = new int[filas*columnas];

     // ejemplo de acceso a datos
     matriz[2*columnas + 3] = 5;

     // Liberación de la memoria
     delete[] matriz;
     ```

> ¿es con triple puntero?

Un puntero simple te permite gestionar un vector de datos (aunque ya has visto que también puede llegar a gestionar una matriz).

Un puntero doble permite gestionar una matriz de datos.

Un puntero triple te permitiría gestionar tres dimensiones de información (algo así como un cubo).

El tema de los punteros puede ser demasiado complejo y extenso. Recuerda que los contenedores de la STL pueden suponer una excelente alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

#### Propuesta

Tu mejor opción es usar un [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) o dependiendo de tus necesidades de inserción y borrado una [`std::list`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list):

```
std::vector<Numero> vn;
std::list<Numero> ln;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // Insercion de elementos
    vn.push_back(i);
    ln.push_back(i);
}
```

Puedes acceder a los elementos del `std::vector` con el operador corchetes (`[]`):

```
std::cout << vn[5] << '\n'; // acceso al sexto elemento.
```

Los contenedores de la [STL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) te permiten manejar la memoria dinámica de manera que no tengas que preocuparte de alojar o liberar los recursos.

---

> #### ¿es con triple puntero? (***)

El triple puntero se corresponde con tres niveles de [indirección](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirecci%C3%B3n), puede ser necesario cuando se trabaja con (por ejemplo) arreglos de tres dimensiones:

```
int tres_d[6][6][6] {};
```

Si quisiéramos acceder al valor de un elemento de `tres_d` deberíamos des-referenciar tres veces:

```
(*(*(*tres_d))) = 3; // Podria escribirse ***tres_d = 3;
```

Si el arreglo fuese de objetos en lugar de enteros (`int`), para poder acceder a los métodos debes des-referenciar tres veces y usar punto (`.`) o des-referenciar dos veces y usar flecha (`->`), pero hay que tener en cuenta que el operador de **acceso a miembro (`.` o `->`) tiene mayor [precedencia](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) que el operador de des-referencia (`*` unario)**, así que deberás usar paréntesis:

```
Numero tres_d[6][6][6] {};
(***tres_d).Metodo();
(**tres_d)->Metodo();
```